# How's the performance of MySql ROW_NUMBER() function with a large dataset?

Tags: mysql, indexing, row-number

How's the performance of MySql ROW_NUMBER() function with a large dataset for a query like this:

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by ts_col, pk_col)
 where other_col = 'value'
```

...

other_col will have a few distinct values

MySQL's explain plan does not show details on it's execution. Will indexing help here?

Comment: How is the performance compared to what?  If you need the row's number then it is pretty quick.  As opposed to rolling your own number generator in an application? Then it is probably going to be faster.    Please not that I am not being snarky but asking for a performance estimate like this begs the question 'compared to what?'

Comment: I need the row's number for doing the pagination queries. The current "Query cost" is 135 on ~7500 rows.

Comment: For pagination you can use limit clause instead of row numbers.

Comment: LIMIT with OFFSET performance deteriorates with larger values. I also need to be able to  do more "deterministic" pagination due to a nature of the data we store, so ROW_NUMBER() seems to be a good choice.

Comment: Try `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` and show it to us.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: This _might_ help:  `INDEX(other_col, ts_col, pk_col)`.

Comment: Pagination is best-done _without_ numbering the rows or using `OFFSET`:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: it's hitting that index. Thanks for the suggestion @RickJames